# NSDate issue with locale

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I'm working on an iPad app that speaks to a private PHP API that I built up to communicate to a database. This API has to transfer Three dates, a starting time, an end time and the current time.

I want to test if the current time is in-between the date range. So I took the times (like 16:50:00) and convert them into NSDates:

```
NSDateFormatter *former = [[NSDateformatter alloc] init];
[former setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
[former setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSDate *fromDate = [former dateFromString:@"10:15:00"];
NSDate *nowDate = [former dateFromString:@"13:25:00"];
NSDate *toDate = [former dateFromString:@"16:30:00"];
```

When I'm now logging the dates by using `NSLog(@"\n%@\n%@\n%@", fromDate, nowDate, toDate);` I see that the locale is incorrect.

It seems as the NSDateFormatter just ignores the locale setting. I also logged the currentLocales identifier which is the right one ("de_DE" in my case"). The locale remains +0000.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks, with kind regards, Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I've removed the previous answer, try the following

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[formatter setTimeZone:zone];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"10:15:00"];

NSLog(@"Time %@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! The `date` got the wrong time, though. It seems like NSDate can't have the right locale. Because it remains +0000. Strange behavior, but a solid workaround. Thanks!